# Classes: I don't really understand them

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working through the book "How to think like a computer scientist"

Now I got this piece of code that I did out of the book

```
class Card:
    suitList = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    rankList = ["narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.rankList[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitList[self.suit])

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        #check the suits
        if self.suit > other.suit: return 1
        if self.suit < other.suit: return -1
        #suits are the same... check ranks
        if self.rank > other.rank: return 1
        if self.rank < other.rank: return -1
        #ranks are the same... it's a tie
        return 0    

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):   
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def printDeck(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print card

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in range(len(self.cards)):
            s = s + " "*i +str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"
        return s

    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        nCards = len(self.cards)
        for i in range(nCards):
            j = random.randrange(i, nCards)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[j] = self.cards[j], self.cards[i]

    def removeCard(self, card):
        if card in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def popCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return (len(self.cards) == 0)

    def deal(self, hands, nCards=999):
        nHands = len(hands)
        for i in range(nCards):
            if self.isEmpty(): break
            card = self.popCard()
            hand = hands[i % nHands]
            hand.addCard(card)

class Hand(Deck):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name

    def addCard(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        s = "Hand " + self.name
        if self.isEmpty():
            return s + "is empty\n"
        else:
            return s + " contains\n" + Deck.__str__(self)

class CardGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = Deck
        self.deck.shuffle()

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
hand = Hand("frank")
deck.deal([hand], 5)
print hand
```

Now I understand the self bit but I don't understand where the

```
self.deck.shuffle()
```

comes from and why it is in the `__init__` function. What I need is a good explanation of classes and some everyday uses that will explain it to me.

Comment: It is not necessarily a *"stuped quiestion"* but it is not one that is suitable for Stack Overflow; see the [FAQ].

Comment: And that should probably be `self.deck = Deck()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` function does what the name implies: initialize an instance of the class.

A class is to a cookie cutter as objects are to cookies: it's a blueprint for creating and interacting with instances in memory.

What are classes and objects good for?  They encapsulate data and functions together into one unit.

Every language in computer science attempts to help you with one thing: managing complexity.  It encapsulates details and hides them from users so they only need to think about how that class maps onto their real life experience in order to use it effectively.

Here's another idea for you: *don't use classes*.  Python is a nice hybrid of object-oriented and functional programming.  If you don't understand classes, write Python without them.  Continue to study until you see the light, then start incorporating them into your designs.